Deserialize a ParameterizeType from a String
I'm currently trying to reconstruct a ParameterizedType instance from a String, for deserialization purposes, but I can't find a working solution:
Getting the ParameterizedType of an Object is relatively simple. I'm using a HashSet as an example here:
ParameterizedType pType = (ParameterizedType)new HashSet<Integer>(){}.getClass().getGenericSuperclass(); 
String pName = pType.getTypeName();

The rawType of pType is defined as class java.util.HashSet
and the actualType is defined as class java.lang.Integer.
So pName is "java.util.HashSet<java.lang.Integer>"
So far so good, but how do I do the inverse?
I can recreate a Class object instance of java.util.HashSet easily:
Class hashSetClass = Class.forName("java.util.HashSet");

but I can't do the same for a parameterized HashSet (This will cause an exception):
Class parameterizedHashSetClass = Class.forName("java.util.HashSet<java.lang.Integer>");

Is there any way to reconstruct the actual ParameterizedType from a String?
One solution I have in mind is doing some kind of runtime code compile trickery: It should be relatively easy to create some runtime code that would create an instance of a HashSet, as described by its pName, and simply return its parameterizedType, but that sounds ridiculously overkill.

Why do you want to create a ParameterizedType? Why not create your own class that represents such a type, parse the string, and construct an instance of your own class? Are you going to give the constructed ParameterizedType to some other APIs? What exactly are you going to do with it?

It's hard to describe: I'm building a visual scripting tool for my engine. The problem I'm facing comes from the need to save and load these scripts during runtime. I can save all the nodes and links to a file, but I can't load them, because I can't read back the value Types, these links are encapsulating. Most of these nodes are created by using reflection during runtime. So I can't create custom classes for each possible value Type. (Well I could, but it's unfeasible)

Did you consider Java's type erasure mechanism?

@forty-two. I read about the issue, but so far it hasn't affected me... At least up to this point I was able to read all the actual value types a method expects and returns. But now that I think about it, maybe I should save the reflection steps I took during the creation of my visual script nodes and redo them during my script loading. That way I don't need to save the parameter types.

Seems like you are inventing your own serialization/deserialization mechanism.  Why don't you use a library that already does this (and handles all this complexity)?  The obvious serialization format is JSON and you are unlikely to find anything the Jackson library cannot handle..

@AndrewL. Very cool library, thank you for the link! Haven't heard of Jackson before. I'm looking into it.

The ParameterizedType object represents the supertype of the type of the object you created with new HashSet<Integer>(){}. So what would be the inverse of the operation you’ve done? From a description of that supertype, somehow get to that anonymous subclass of HashSet? What you actually want, to get from a string "java.util.HashSet<java.lang.Integer>" to a parameterized Class object, is impossible, as said by others (there is no such thing at all, there is only one Class object representing the HashSet class), but it’s also not the inverse of anything you did before that.
